# How to implement Inheritance in Realm (iOS, Objective C)

Tags: ios, realm

I have a entities as:

- 'Person' - Abstract class.
- 'Contact' - subclass from Person
- 'User' - subclass from Person
- 'Activity' - which contains a relatedPerson as Person type, but it can be Contact or User.

My question: When I caching the 'Activity', Realm cached the relatedPerson as 'Person' type and lose all the data of 'User' or 'Contact'. How to fix this?

My classes structure is

```
@interface Person : RLMObject

@property NSString *uID;

- (NSString *)displayName;
...
@end

@interface Contact : Person

@property NSString *fullName;
...
@end

@interface User : Person

@property NSString *nickname;
...
@end


@interface Activity : RLMObject

@property NSString *uID;
@property NSDate *createdAt;

@property Person *relatedPerson;

@end
```

Comment: What is the `GAPerson`?

Comment: Sorry, it's Person:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm does not yet directly support inheritance of the type you're after. Support for it is being tracked in [GitHub issue 1109](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109). In the meantime, you can see a few different approaches to emulating inheritance in the comments of that issue by [@jpsim](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109#issuecomment-143834756) and [@mrackwitz](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109#issuecomment-143985250). Which approach is most suitable for you will depend on the requirements of your model.